# values_list query is returning the foreign keys pk rather than it's value

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to get all the categories currently used in `Recipes` without any duplicates, by querying `CategoryToRecipe`.

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class CategoryToRecipe(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


query_set = CategoryToRecipe.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

`query_set` is returning numbers, which I assume are the `ID` for `Category`, not the name (e.g. Lunch, Dinner, etc.).

How do I get the actual name string of `Category`?

Comment: `query_set = CategoryToRecipe.objects.values_list('name__name', flat=True).distinct()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem  said in comments you are not accessing the related object `name` attribute you do that using joins and which is done in ORM like this:

```
query_set = CategoryToRecipe.objects.values_list('name__name', flat=True).distinct()
```